# GitHub Action share token between jobs to reuse

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have a simple workflow where i wanted to generate installation token once to use in entire workflow jobs. The static variable values getting shared between jobs but not the token.

In this output you can see its able to parse output of "test_var" but not for "installation_token". Per my understanding the value for token should be "***" and not ""

[image]

[image]

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'terraform/**'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  validate:
    needs:
      - fmt-check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: terraform validate

    outputs:
      installation_token: ${{ steps.get_installation_token.outputs.token }}
      test_var: "Hello"

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Generate token
        uses: tibdex/github-app-token@v1
        id: get_installation_token
        with: 
          app_id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
          private_key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}

  plan:
    needs:
      - validate
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: terraform plan

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - run: echo "${{ needs.validate.outputs.installation_token }}"
      - run: echo "${{ needs.validate.outputs.test_var }}"
```

Comment: Did you set the secrets `APP_ID` and `PRIVATE_KEY` in the repository as specified ? (`app_id` = ID of the GitHub App & `private_key` = Private key of the GitHub App (can be Base64 encoded))

Comment: Yes I did. Removed env:var section to shorten the question

Comment: Please `run: echo '${{ toJSON(needs) }}'` and add the (redacted) output to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @Rio: Indentation of the second job `plan` is off. Looks like a copy/paste issue.